# Recursion in Javascript stops without finishing the previous for loops

Tags: javascript, recursion

I wanted to recursively traverse a tree but the recursive function stops once it reaches the deepest nested element, instead of finishing every other loop that came before it. I replicated the problem below, and got the output:

```
1
[2, [3, [4, 5], 6], 7]
2
[3, [4, 5], 6]
3
[4, 5]
4
5
```

when I should be getting this instead:

```
1
[2, [3, [4, 5], 6], 7]
2
[3, [4, 5], 6]
3
[4, 5]
4
5
6
7
8
```

any help would be deeply appreciated.

```
function recurse(lst) {
    for (i=0; i<lst.length; i++) {
        console.log(lst[i]);
        if (Array.isArray(lst[i])) {
            recurse(lst[i]);
        }
    }
}

recurse([1, [2, [3, [4, 5], 6], 7], 8]);
```

Comment: You should declare your `i` variable as a local variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare the loop variable *i* with [*let*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) which will declare a block scope local variable:

```js
function recurse(lst) {
    for (let i=0; i<lst.length; i++) {
        console.log(lst[i]);
        if (Array.isArray(lst[i])) {
            recurse(lst[i]);
        }
    }
}

recurse([1, [2, [3, [4, 5], 6], 7], 8]);
```